# Find two maximum ratios in array with non intersecting indices

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Assume we have array: [1, 1, 3, 10, 11, 2, 9].
I can't google/stackoveflow/figure out algorithm that can:
Find in given array two pairs of numbers [n1, n2] and [m1, m2] which have max sum of their ratio max( (n2/n1) + (m2/m1) ) such that:

1. n1 <= n2, m1<=m2
2. index(n1) < index(n2) < index(m1) < index(m2).
   In given example: we have [1(n1), 1, 3, 10, 11(n2), 2(m1), 9(m2)].
   We can't have other 1 and 10 because they will be between n1 and n2 in array.

My current idea:

1. Find min and max, such as index(min) < index(max).
2. Find between them other pair of min and max such as index(max) < index(min)

But can't figure out how to prove that it's that what i'm looking for. Or is there another approach?

I wrote straight solution:

```
def max_ratio(x):
    # x - list of integers 
    ratio = 0
    values = []
    for i in range(len(x)-3):
        for j in range(i+1, len(x)-2):
            for k in range(j+1, len(x)-1):
                for l in range(k+1, len(x)):
                    if (x[l]/x[k]) + (x[j]/x[i]) > ratio:
                        ratio = (x[l]/x[k]) + (x[j]/x[i])
                        values = [i, j, k,l]
    return [x[values[0]], x[values[1]], x[values[2]], x[values[3]]]
```

But it's O(n^4), can't figure ot good algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Granted that I do not know what the purpose of the algorithm you seek is, I would probably proceed in the following manner:

We'll have to check in every step (I won't  write it) to have at least four different indices.

```
# We'll need at least 4 numbers
# so at least 0, 1, 2, 3 indices
# let's start from index 3

# define abs max index and loop
For max_abs_index = 3 to A.length:

# Get max
m2 = A[max_abs_index] 

# Get max on array to m2 index
n2 = max(A) [ 0, max_abs_index ) 

# So: 
# index(n2) < index(m2) 

# Get min on array from n2 to m2 index
m1 = min(A) ( index(n2), max_abs_index ) 

# Get min on array from 0 to n2 index
n1 = min(A) [ 0, index(n2)  ) 

# So: 
# index(n1) < index(n2) < index(m1) < index(m2)

# calculate ratio
ratio.push( m2/m1 + n2/n1 )
```

max_ratio = max(ratio) [ 0, ratio.length ]

To find the maximum it will take O(n)
To find the minimum it will take O(n)

So we can say that an iteration will take

4 x O(n) ~ O(n)

We'll have to do it n-times so altogether it will take

O(n) x O(n) = O(n²)

Comment: And what if the 2nd maximum is after m2? Like 1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4 ?

Comment: You've specified as a requirement that the following rule must be true: index(n1) < index(n2) < index(m1) < index(m2); in the example you post it will be: m2 = 7, n2 = 6, m1 = 3 and n1 = 1.

Comment: finding two max won't always help us =( for example - on array [28, 12, 29, 18, 12, 19, 19, 22, 22, 5, 19, 18, 2, 14, 8, 21, 25, 10, 6, 17] result must be - [5, 19, 2, 25]

Comment: Now it will work and it will find [ m2 = 25, n2 = 29, m1 = 2, n1 = 5 ] (check my edit)